# How to figure out why ReSharper is not rebuilding unit test project before running?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper, rebuild

Recently I am having an annoying problem. When I go to Unit Test Sessions window and run some tests, ReSharper seems to completely ignore any changes in my code(even in the code of the test itself!) and does not rebuild anything. Because of that I have to rebuild everything manually. I think that problem is too generic to post on bug-tracker so I would like to find at least any additional information. For MsBuild I can always enable diagnostic logging and track all its decisions during build. How can I find what is the problem with ReSharper?

Versions:
Visual Studio 2015 Pro Update 2; ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you installed the Rider EAP by any chance? There is a bug in the latest EAP (EAP7) that sets the build action before running tests to "Never", and since the global settings file is shared between Rider and ReSharper, this also causes ReSharper to not build tests before running. The fix is simple - just change the value in the drop down in the unit test runner window. See the [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-1393) for more details.

[image: Screenshot]

One thing I'm not sure on is if this is a recurring issue - i.e. the value gets reset to "Never" every time Rider opens the unit testing window. This is an unfortunate bug, and will definitely be fixed for EAP8.

Comment: here's a [screenshot](http://oi64.tinypic.com/2hfjf4w.jpg) showing where exactly you can alter the setting that @citizenmatt is talking about

Comment: OMG, that was exactly my case!

Comment: @AlexandruMarculescu I've added your screenshot to the answer. citizenmatt: I hope you don't mind :)